# Target Types order in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: publishing, web8.5, topology-manager

We're using SDL Web 8.5 with Topology Manager. We'd like to change the order the Target Types are shown when Publish button is clicked.

I can see topology row in the ENTITY_SETS table has a collection of Environments. Changing the order there doesn't change the order in the Publish Popup and changing the order in the Environments row doesn't either.

So, two questions..

1. I see in the CM database: TARGET_TYPES,
   PUBLICATION_TARGETS and PUB_TARGET_ASSOCIATIONS tables, but I don't
   understand... isn't this a duplication of having the Mapping in the
   Topology Manager? Is this there just for backward compatibility
   (since in Topology Manager we also associate Publications to Target
   Types/Environments/Purposes).
2. How can I change the order of the Target Types in the Publish Popup?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1):

1. As far as I know yes, they're there for legacy reasons. You can install and set up publishing in legacy mode using the old Target Types and Publication Targets. The "new" or "simulated" Target Types have a 1-1 relation with Purposes, see below (Properties of a Business Process Type):
   [image]
2. Don't know unfortunately, but this is a duplicate of [this question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-publishing-targets-in-publish-dialog-box)

Comment: Ad 1) To be precise: for Topology Manager based publishing, you still have Target Types (as part of a BPT), but for backward compatibility purposes, there is also an “emulated” Publication Target for each Target Type. This is to ensure that code that expects a Publication Target (e.g. custom resolver) still works.