# Target order in publish dialog

Tags: web8.5, cme, topology-manager

Is it possile to change the order of targets in Publish Dialog? We get Live first and then Staging.
We just migrated from Tridion 2013 to SDL Web 8.5, and when we created Business Process Type, we got that order.

Staging is id 23 and Live is id 22, so we get Live first in Publish Dialog.

That is confusing for users, in the old system they had Staging first.

Is there any way to change this order?

Thank you.

I know it may be a duplicate question, but it has no answer to my problem: [Target Types order in SDL Web 8.5](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19238/target-types-order-in-sdl-web-8-5)

Comment: If you had the purpose defined ( Staging, Live) on topology, in that case when you created the Business Process Type based on the Topology Type it should have shown you Staging first followed by Live.
If you had setup the Business Process Type wrong by changing the Target Name and if you have publish all the pages to the new target type. 
One option is to create a new business process type and set the target properly and Convert-TcmPublishStates from the Source Target to Destination Target.

Assume you had removed all the Legacy Target after the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, that was my thought, but I expected there was other way :( That implies stopping the service for a while, and this is production environment.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Marko, No, It's not possible by configuration, currently getting the target type list getting ordered by ID in the SQL query.

Here is the query executed in the backend by coreservice to getting the Target Type while open up the publishing popup dialog. (/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Lists.svc/GetList with filter {"id":"tcm:0-5-1","filter":{"ItemTypes":["tcm:65538"]},"columns":3}).

> exec EDA_TARGET_TYPES_GETLIST
> @iPUBLICATION_ID=5,@iBUSINESS_PROCESS_TYPE_ID=NULL

To get it to fix either by GUI extensions or by fixing the Topology Type and Business Process mapping correctly as @Anand mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no, it is not possible by any configuration. But I guess you can always try to create GUI extension that changes order of the items in whichever way you want. Publish dialog is extensible, so you can extend its UI and try to reorder items.